# How Do i shrink to fit image the banner IN SHOPIFY

Tags: css, shopify, banner

How Do i shrink to fit image the banner **IN SHOPIFY**

i am new to shopify not sure how it works so let me know if you have any suggestion. i have attached few example so you have an idea what i am talking about.

```css
<div class="slider-area" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="slideshow-section">
  <div class="slider-active owl-carousel">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}   
    <div class="single-slider single-slider-book1 bg-img" style="background-image: url({% if block.settings.slider_bg_image %}
                                                                 {{ block.settings.slider_bg_image | img_url: 'master' }}
                                                                 {% else %}https://via.placeholder.com/1545x950{% endif %})">
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="slider-animation slider-content-book fadeinup-animated {% if block.settings.slider_content_position_right %}content_right{% endif %}">
          {% if block.settings.slider_title_1 != '' %}
          <h1 class="animated" style="color: {{ block.settings.slider_title_1_color }}">{{ block.settings.slider_title_1 }}</h1>
          {% endif %}
          
          {% if block.settings.slider_title_2 != '' %}
          <h2 class="animated" style="color: {{ block.settings.slider_title_2_color }}">{{ block.settings.slider_title_2 }}</h2>
          {% endif %}
          
          {% if block.settings.slider_subtitle != '' %}
          <p class="animated" style="color: {{ block.settings.slider_subtitle_color }}">{{ block.settings.slider_subtitle }}</p>
          {% endif %}
          
          {% if block.settings.slider_btn_text != '' %}
          <a href="{{ block.settings.slider_btn_url }}" style="color: {{ block.settings.slider_btn_color }}; 
                                                               background-color: rgba({{ block.settings.slider_btn_bg_color }}, 1)">
            {{ block.settings.slider_btn_text }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>



{% for block in section.blocks %}  
<style>
  .slider-content-book h1 span {color: {{ block.settings.slider_title_1_span_color }};}
  .slider-animation.slider-content-book.content_right {text-align: right;}
  .slider-animation.slider-content-book.content_right p {margin-left: auto;}
  .slider-content-book > a:hover {box-shadow: 0 10px 35px -7px rgba({{ block.settings.slider_btn_bg_color }}, 0.9);}
</style>
{% endfor %}



<script>
  $('.slider-active').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    autoplay: {% if section.settings.slider_autoplay_enable %}true{% else %}false{% endif %},
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    item: 1,
    rtl:true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      768: {
        items: 1
      },
      1000: {
        items: 1
      }
    }
  })
</script>





{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Slider- Book",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "slider_autoplay_enable",
        "label": "Enable Slider Autoplay",
        "default": true
      }
 ],
    "blocks": [
  {
   "type": "slide",
   "name": "Slide",
   "settings": [
    {
     "type": "image_picker",
     "id": "slider_bg_image",
     "label": "Slider BG Image"
    },
    {
     "type": "header",
     "content": "Slider Content"
    },
                {
                  "type": "checkbox",
                  "id": "slider_content_position_right",
                  "label": "Slider Content Position Right",
                  "default": false
                },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "id": "slider_title_1",
     "label": "Title 1",
     "default": "<span>Knowledge</span> is",
     "info": "Use '<span>' tag for color text e.g. <span>Knowledge</span> is"
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "id": "slider_title_2",
     "label": "Title 2",
     "default": "Power."
    },
    {
     "type": "textarea",
     "id": "slider_subtitle",
     "label": "Sub-title",
     "default": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "id": "slider_btn_text",
     "label": "Button Text",
     "default": "More Books"
    },
    {
     "type": "url",
     "id": "slider_btn_url",
     "label": "Button URL",
     "default": "\/collections\/all"
    },
                {
                  "type": "header",
                  "content": "Color [See More Color](https:\/\/www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "slider_title_1_color",
                  "label": "Title 1 Color"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "slider_title_1_span_color",
                  "label": "Title 1 span text Color"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "slider_title_2_color",
                  "label": "Title 2 Color"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "slider_subtitle_color",
                  "label": "Sub-title Color"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "slider_btn_color",
                  "label": "Button text Color"
                },
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "id": "slider_btn_bg_color",
                  "label": "Button BG Color",
                  "info": "Put RGB value e.g. 56, 40 , 25"
                }
   ]   
  }
 ],
 "presets":[
  {
   "name": "Slider- Book",
   "category": "slider",
   "blocks":[
    {
     "type": "slide"
    },
    {
     "type": "slide"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

**3 different screen with same picture**

[TABLET SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slGLo.jpg)

[DESKTOP SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oa5x.jpg)

[PHONE SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32b2f.jpg)

[ACTUAL IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhd91.jpg)

you can see a preview here 
https://stashcbd-com.myshopify.com/?preview_theme_id=31932481611

Answer (score 0):

The image size ( if you are referring to the original size of the image ) is controlled via the filter `img_url: 'master'` at the moment. But that syntax is deprecated. You can read more here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/deprecated-filters#named-size-parameters

So the proper way to size the image is to use specific sizes instead:

`{{ block.settings.slider_bg_image | img_url: '2048x2048' }}`

Where `2048x2048` is width and height.

Now if you are referring to sizing down the image via CSS, that's a whole different story and you don't have problems with the Shopify logic but with the CSS and the question is not asked properly.